# use lxml to get value from from child with parent having a given value

Tags: loops, lxml

I am new to using lxml with python, and I am having trouble parsing and xml file the way I want.  I have searched around and can't seem to find anything that explains this well.  What I need to do is iterate though child elements underneath a parent with a fixed value.

For example: I need to loop through all elements under the name "variable", but only underneath the station with id ="VTBRA".

```
<station id="VTBRA" name="RT 7 Brandon" elev="407" lat="43.76728" lon="-73.05017" distance="" provider="VTRANS">

<ob time="16 Feb 7:30 am EST">
<variable var="T" description="Temp" unit="F" value="9"/>
<variable var="RH" description="Relh" unit="%" value="81"/>
<variable var="FF" description="Wind" unit="mph" value="1"/>
<variable var="DD" description="Direction" unit="deg" value="85"/>
<variable var="DDCARD" description="Wind Card" unit="direction" value="E"/>
<variable var="FFGUST" description="Gust" unit="mph" value="4"/>
<variable var="VV" description="Visibility" unit="miles" value="3.68"/>
<variable var="STAQUAL" description="Station Quality" unit="" value="OK"/>
```

I am currently modify a code snippit like this:

for elt in node.getiterator('station'):
    provider=elt.get('provider','Unknown')

```
 for  elt in node.getiterator('variable'):
      if elt.get('var', 'Unknown') == "T":
          print elt.get('value','Unknown')
```

This code loops through all instances of "variable" both inside and outside of the station with the id of "VTBRA".  Is there a argument or something that can be added to get iterator to only loop through the variable tags underneath the selected station id?  Or should I be a different function entirely?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `xpath()` function to select the `<station>` element with `VTBRA` as `id` and traverse all its `<variable>` elements, like:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys

tree = etree.parse(sys.argv[1])
for v in tree.xpath('//station[@id="VTBRA"]//variable'):
    ## Do whatever you want with each "variable" element. In this case I print its
    ## "var" attribute.
    print(v.get('var'))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py xmlfile
```

That yields (after fixing your non-wellformed `xml` data):

```
T
RH
FF
DD
DDCARD
FFGUST
VV
STAQUAL
```